# How to secure requesting post - C# and PHP

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I have a problems with C#, PHP, MYSQLi.
I made a form for Login & Registration system with

---

This a simple C# function for user registration.

IEnumerator registrar(
    string name,
    string username,
    string email,
    string password
) {

```
// This is what sends messages to our php script
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

// The fields are the variables we are sending
form.AddField("name", name);
form.AddField("username", username);
form.AddField("email", email);
form.AddField("password", password);

//string url = "http://www.my-server.com/registrar.php";
string url = "http://localhost/registrar.php";

UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form);

// Wait for php to send something back to unity
yield return www.SendWebRequest();

if (
    www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError
) {
    Debug.Log("Error!");
} else {
    Debug.Log("Complete!");
}}
```

__

```
// Database variables
$db_host        = "localhost";
$db_user        = "root";
$db_password    = "test";
$db_name        = "test";

// Connect to database.
$db = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

// User variables
$name           = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
$username       = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
$email          = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
$password       = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
$password_hash  = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// E-mail can not be empty
if(
    !empty($email)
    &&
    !empty($username)
    &&
    !empty($password)
) {
    // Insert user data
    $db->query("INSERT INTO `user`(`username`, `name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('$username', '$name', '$email', '$password_hash')");

    // Display...
    echo "Success!";
} else {
    // Display an error
    echo "Error!";
}
?>
```

Everything is OK, The PHP code are work to.

But my problem now what gonna happen if the hackers get the URL of registration page, And make for himself a form just like my form and use my URL of registration page and using.

This is my problem, This problem will hack the Game data Like (Score, Total play, Time play, Otherss data).

So how can I protect & secure (request post) Do I have do something in PHP or C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a glance I can identify some weaknesses in your code:

- You are not using HTTPS. Traffic between the client and server could be intercepted and seen in clear.
- You are not using prepared statements. While `real_escape_string` is probably ok, know that: 1) It is altering the data. 2) It depends on the character set configured for the database connection (which you do not seem to be setting).
- You are not validating user registration (i.e. sending an email with a code and waiting for it to confirm). Which means that it is easy to create lots of fake accounts.

---

What you ask seem to be authenticating your application to the server. The server does not know if the client is valid (it could be third party software doing the requests), so you want to find a way to make sure.

No, there is no way to do it. Not if the user is in control of the client and can reverse engineer it.

[Fredrik Schön answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56411173/402022) offers an solution that is useful in a different context. The idea is there will be a "password" `apikey` that identifies your application, and the server will check if it is correct. This is useful if I want two applications to connect... however, when one application is on the user machine, this is not secure at all.

Remember that your client could be modified, or the `apikey` stolen, since it is running on the client machine.

You could add a digital signature to the client (to add an integrity check on your client, so that it can verify that it has not been modified), yet that can also be circumvented.

On this point, it is all mitigations. There is no way to do it.

---

> hack the Game data Like (Score, Total play, Time play, Otherss data).

**Never trust the client**

There should be no API to do these. There should be no way for the client to set the score (or to set any other form of reward). Instead the client sends *events* to the server (they can be as granular as one per user input, this is what you would be doing on a multiplayer client-server game anyway), and the server decides on score, rewards, etc.

I repeat, there would be no API. There would be no way for the client to just send how much you played.

*Removing the process is the only way to guarantee you removed a risk. Otherwise, it is all mitigations.*

---

*A search for [Anti-Cheat at gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=anti-cheat) can give you some ideas.*

---

**Addendum**:

The problem of a *game client* that accesses a web form and a malicious user that creates a custom client that accesses the same form... is not fundamentally different from the problem of a *web browser* that accesses a web form and a malicious user that creates a custom client that accesses the same form. All server side security measures for the web apply for the game. And please notice that basing this security on a particular browser is not a good idea.

What we want is not to prevent the creation of the third party custom client, nor to make it useless. Instead to make sure it can at best do the same things that the legitimate client can do.

There is an API between the client and the server. If there is something in that API that allows the client to do something that the client *should not* do (such as setting a fake score), then the server and its API must be reworked so that it is not possible.

Comment: thank you so much @Theraot for this answer. 
i can understand you, but this is not my actual code :) my actual code is very long code i just write this code for this questions. 
my problem is, today i found a tool called **(DevXUnity-Unpacker Magic Tools)** this tool will unpack unity game staff like code :( 
so the hacker can view all my code they will find the registrar link _(http://localhost/registrar.php)_ or other link like inserting score data, so they can make own form and use my code like inserting score data. its ok if tay hack my score but i do not like to use php links.

Comment: @Mr.Ali php is not inherently insecure - despite what some might say - yet it is not secure by default either. If you do not want a rouge client inserting score data, do not offer that on the server API. The client must only tell the server what the user does, and the server must calculare how much score gives you as reward, update it, and send it to the client. At no point there must be an option of the client to tell the server how much score you get, that API should not exist.

Comment: @Mr.Ali you are giving me the impression that you are worried that the hacker will alter your PHP somehow. I'm am assuming the PHP code is in a remote server. Not in the Unity Game, not in the client machine. Where the hacker cannot see it, nor edit it, unless the server is vulnerable by other means. And that should be, if it is PHP or not.

Comment: sorry if i'm bothering you sir, but how dose Call of duty or other big games save data. you know why  i'm tray this. because i want save and load their data when player delete the game on their phones and reinstall the game agin.

Comment: @Mr.Ali On the server, of course. I am not suggesting to have no server. Just do not have a server with the option for a client (legitimate or not) to tell it about rewards (score, et al). All those must be decided by the server. I have gone on more length on this topic at [How do I avoid users hacking my network games from the client side?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/140592/10408), you may also be interested in [The state that is synced when a window is broken in a FPS game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/160701/10408) (you will find links that go on more detail there).

Answer (score -1):

Add authentication through an API key! You can make this as advanced or as simple as you want:

```cs
form.AddField("apikey", apikey);
```

```php
if ($_POST['apikey'] != "<the_api_key>")
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for answering me. But i'm sorry i didn't understand what you are doing, i already edited my question and i added my PHP code, could you please edit the code for me just to i understand what you mean about (api key).

Comment: If you roll out your C#-application to your clients directly, then do you not get more security with an api-key.

Comment: @user6537157 hanks for answe, but hackers can unpack unity games and view all c# code its ok to hack my game like scroe but i dont like to do in php link:(

Comment: @Mr.Ali yes your code can always reserved. And thats the reason why the apikey dont give more security.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot ensure that hackers cant post a false score.

You can try on server-side to verify the data (like "is this score possible for played time?").
Or you can do the most as possible on server-side (your C#-application call your php-backend when the user starts a game and return a token (= random string) and measures time).

And you can enforce https on server-side.