# how can I detect tampered big file in a short time?

Tags: security, cryptography, reverse-engineering, digital-signature

I felt very frustrated in the battle with cheaters of my game. I found a lot of hackers tampered my game data to avoid the anti-cheat system. I have tried some methods to verify if the game data has tampered or not. Such as encrypting my asset-package or check the hash of the package header.

However, I got stuck on the issue that my asset-package is huge. It is almost 1~3GB. I know the digital signature is doing very well in verifying data. But I need this to be done in almost real-time.

It seems I have to make a trade-off between verifying the whole file and the performance. Does there any way to verify a huge file in a short-time?

Comment: Try putting the parts hackers might want to hack, like saved positions or running scores in a separate smaller file.

Comment: @rossum I have tried something like that. But attackers always can find some amazing method to make use of assets look harmless

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411088/how-to-secure-requesting-post-c-sharp-and-php/56411611#56411611

Answer (score 2):

AES-NI based hashing such as [Meow Hash](https://mollyrocket.com/meowhash) can easily reach 16 bytes *per cycle* on a single thread, that is, for data already on-cache, it process *tens of gigabytes* of input in a second. Obviously in reality the memory and disk I/O speed becomes the limiting factor, but they apply on any method, so you can think of them as the upper limit. Since it's not designed for security, it's also possible for cheaters to quickly figure out a viable collision.

But, even if you figure out a sweet spot between speed and security, you're still relying on cheaters not forwarding your file/memory I/O. Additionally, it's still possible for the cheaters to just NOP any asset verification call. Since you care about cheaters, I'd assume this is an online game. The more common practice is to rearchitect the game to prevent cheating even with a broken asset. On [Valorant](https://technology.riotgames.com/news/demolishing-wallhacks-valorants-fog-war), they move the line of sight calculation to server-side. [LoL](https://eune.leagueoflegends.com/en-pl/news/dev/dev-null-anti-cheat-kernel-driver/) add kernel driver

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try out Meow Hash. It would be  It would be nice if you could share some more detail about how to prevent cheating with a broken asset. : )

Comment: The "details" are essentially on the last two links, rearchitecting the game depends on what each game.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'll check it out. Thank you.